# org-table alignment issues in osx

Tags: org-mode, osx

I am used to my tables aligning nicely when I hit C-c C-c in Linux. In Emacs for OS X (emacsforosx.com) this does not behave on my system.

[image]

It works in Aquamacs.

Comment: Select a monospaced font please with `M-x set-default-font`, that should resolve it.

Comment: Agree that the problem is that you're using a non-monospaced font.  @wasamasa: could you convert your comment to an answer, adding a little more detail to flesh it out?

Comment: Very well, done.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While org-mode is a very flexible tool, it has some very hardcoded limitations in its core functionality.  The one you're encountering is the reliance on a monospaced font (such as Andale Mono, Monaco or Menlo to name a few ones your OS X system should come with) to display tables in an aligned fashion.

There are multiple options how you can solve it.  If you are already relying on monospaced fonts, set Emacs' default font in your init file to a monospaced one:

```
(setq default-frame-alist '((font . "Monaco-12")))
```

Alternatively, customize the `org-table` face with `M-x customize-face RET org-table RET` to use a monospaced font to make only org-mode tables display correctly.

Comment: Thanks! I suspected that was the issue, but I apparently did something wrong when I tried to switch to Inconsolata to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue in the OS X Emacs 24 window-system. My default font is variable width, so naturally my Org-tables were not aligning properly. To continue with @wasamasa's solution for customizing the font for just the `org-table` mode and keeping a default variable width font for everything else, I found this solution helpful: [`variable-pitch` for org-mode, fixed-pitch for tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3761399/2623701)