# Re-Aligning Issue with org-mode tables in spite of monospaced font (Emacs 25.3 / Mac OS X)

Tags: org-mode, osx, org-table

I changed from Aquamacs to Emacs for Mac OS X (25.3). Now I have an issue with org-mode tables. After writing and before re-aligning it looks like this:
[image: before re-align]

After re-align the table with `C-c C-c` or `TAB` it looks like this:
[image: after re-align]

When I save the file, restart Emacs and open the org-file again everything looks fine:
[image: after restart]

Further changes to the table with following re-aligning leed again to the alignemnt-issue.
[image]

After another restart the table looks fine again. I found a similar problem because of non-use of a monospaced font [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5591/org-table-alignment-issues-in-osx/8153). But the default font is monospaced (Menlo). A Change to Monaco-font does not solve the problem either. (`C-u C-x =` shows

```
mac-ct:-*-Menlo-normal-normal-normal-*-12-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1 (#x4C)
```

and

```
mac-ct:-*-Monaco-normal-normal-normal-*-12-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1 (#x4F)
```

respectively. Does anyone have an idea, why this happens and how to solve it?

Edit: I am using Emacs via Spotlight only.

Comment: Are you using emacs in a terminal?

Comment: I think I'm experiencing the same problem, using (GUI) Emacs from homebrew `railwaycat/emacsmacport/emacs-mac emacs-25.3-mac-6.8`. Tables align themselves after killing the buffer and reopening (no restart needed) but any change to the table causes the alignment to break again.

Comment: It looks like that is not only an alignment issue. If you compare the original table with the first aligned one you miss several letters, e.g., at the word `incidunt`. It might be that you have a display problem. (E.g., incomplete redraw.)

Comment: Me, too. It is a display problem because the table alignment is fine when file is displayed in a  terminal window. (GNU Emacs 25.3.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin17.2.0, NS appkit-1561.10 Version 10.13.1 (Build 17B48)) of 2017-11-22, Org mode version 9.1.5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `org-mode` version 9.1.5-10 release 2018-01-02. I had a similar problem and it seems that it was caused by a bug in one of the recent small updates to `org-mode`. The latest update from 02/01/2018 seems to have sorted this problem out. `M-x list-packages RET` choose `org` 20180102.

A per the comment below, I have this in .emacs file as well
`(add-to-list 'package-archives '("org" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/") t)`

Comment: I had a similar problem, it seems to have been caused by a bug in one of the December releases of `org-mode` 9.15. I re-installed `org-mode` with the latest patches. `M-x list-packages` find `org` 20180102 and try installing that version. In my case at least, it was the bug from one of the recent version that has been fixed, apparently.

Comment: Drew: I hope you are happy now :) - not being sarcastic.

Comment: Fixed it for me! FWIW I had to add `(add-to-list 'package-archives '("org" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/") t)` to my init.el to see the new version.